# Is there anyway to get svn commit event without svn hook permission?

Tags: svn, hook

I think I need a continuous integration service, but someone who has svn repository privilege is too busy to add the svn pre-commit hook. Is there anyway to get the repository commit event without privilege? If there's no such way, I may use a crawl to check update per minute.

Comment: Which CI systems are you looking at? CCNet polls on a set interval, no hook required.

Comment: Please provide more details like the SVN Client you are using, why do you need a CI service specifically............make it as descriptive as you can!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`svnsync`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt) to mirror the repo into one where you can set hooks. `synsync` operates at the repository access library layer, so it will call commit (and other) hooks on the destination repository just like any other client will.

Comment: Thanks, but I just need to check build failure and send notification to some guys, not host the repository for myself. I think **svnsync** is clone the repository to my place but it won't get the new commit event after synchronized.

Comment: svnsync works at a high enough level that it should trigger any hooks present on the destination repository when it copies the commits over.

Comment: And I just tested - it does indeed call post-commit hooks.

Comment: @bdonlan But without post-commit hook, I need to run `svnsync sync` periodically, right?

Comment: That is correct. With no post-commit hook on the source repo, you will always need to implement some kind of polling. This is just so you can re-use the built-in hooks of your CI service without having to rewrite them to be polling-based.